# req.body is undefined in nodemailer

Tags: json, undefined, nodemailer, body-parser, req

I have an issue with req.body being undefined in nodemailer.

React: I have the whole function written and all the data is correctly passed. console.log(data) gives me the correct object.

```
 axios
  .post(`${this.state.API_URL}/email/send`, JSON.stringify(data))
  .then((response) => {
  });
```

Express: just the important parts for the nodemailer.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const emailRoute = require("./routes/api/emailRoute");
app.use("/email", emailRoute);
```

emailRoute:

```
 router.post("/send", async (req, res) => {
  const EmailAddress = process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "hotmail",
    auth: {
      user: EmailAddress,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
    },
  });

  await transporter.sendMail(
    {
      from: req.body.email,
      to: EmailAddress,
      subject: "Email from app",
      text: `name: ${req.body.name} 
      current-role: ${req.body.role} 
      sports-car: ${req.body.enthusiast} 
      comment: ${req.body.comment}`,
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(503).json(err);
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(200).json("email sent");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I'm getting the email to my email account, but this is what I get.

```
from [unknown]
      name: undefined
      current-role: undefined
      sports-car: undefined
      comment: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see that the parameters received in the server from the client?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. So no JSON.stringify(data) just data in axios.

```
 axios
.post(`${this.state.API_URL}/email/send`, data)
.then((response) => {
});
```

and in emailRoute

```
  const EmailAddress = process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "hotmail",
auth: {
  user: EmailAddress,
  pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
},
});


 await transporter.sendMail(
{
  from: EmailAddress,
  to: EmailAddress,
  subject: "Email from app",
  text: 
 `name: ${req.body.name} 
  email: ${req.body.email}
  current-role: ${req.body.role} 
  sports-car: ${req.body.enthusiast} 
  comment: ${req.body.comment}`,
 }
```

the email address for 'user' and 'from' should be the same. I thought I could use the sender's email for 'from' which I get from the form in React, but I guess not. For my case I'm sending and receiving email from the same email account of mine, and I'm just passing the sender's email address in the 'text'.

Answer (score 0):

You Have To Use Body parser In Every Single Router!
So If You Didn't Add It To Email Route Then Add It!
All The Best

Comment: Still the same result after importing everything. is this what you mean or I have to pass body-parser as argument or something ? to the router.post?   const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
require("dotenv").config();

Comment: OK First Of All can you just specify the files you have

Comment: and you don't have to but as an argument at all that's will made a bug

Comment: I'm Sorry English Is Not My Language

Comment: as in the question, I have a react component where I make axios call, server.js which has all the back-end and emailRoute which has nodemailer. I imported body-parser both in server.js and emailRoute.js.